# Interaction of UIImageView and UITapGestureRecognizer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have several UIImageViews on my screen and if one of them is tapped, it has to change his color. As I had the same problem with UIView, the solution was:

```
    func viewTapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    viewTouched = recognizer.view as UIView!
    thisCard.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

}
```

But I haven't found the similar action for the image view. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `tintColor` of your `UIImageView`s :

```
func imageViewTapped(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let imageView = recognizer.view as? UIImageView
      else { return }
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `UIImageView` not working?
If not, check `userInteractionEnabled`.

Set `userInteractionEnabled` to true.

**UIImageView**

```
 public var userInteractionEnabled: Bool // default is NO
```

Comment: Yes, it works now. The first answer has fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension of image view

```
extension UIImage {
    func tintWithColor(color:UIColor)->UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // flip the image
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -self.size.height)

        // multiply blend mode
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Overlay)

        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        color.setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        // create uiimage
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage

    }
}
```

Now use like this

```
yourImageView.image = yourImageView.image!.tintWithColor(UIColor.orangeColor())
```